# Is Vivi a Celestial Dragon?

Tags: one-piece

According to the latest episode 653 of One Piece, Joker says to Trafalgar Law that the creators of world government were 20 families which are called **Celestial Dragons**. One of the 20 families was from Alabasta and its name is Nefertari Family. One person who comes to mind when we talk about Alabasta is Vivi, *the princess of Alabasta*, who belongs to Nefertari Family.

**So is Vivi a Celestial Dragon**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The World Nobles, also known as the Celestial Dragons (天竜人 Tenryūbito, literally meaning "Heavenly Dragon Folk"), are the descendants of nineteen of the Twenty Kings who established what is now known as the World Government.

(Source: [Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/World_Noble))

So no, she is not a Celestial Dragon.

Comment: but all twenty families made world government together so why Vivi is not a celestial dragon and Joker is?

Comment: @MurtazaA. Because the Nefertari refused to go live in Mariejois and live among the filthy common folk. If the Nefertari moved to Mariejois at the time of creation Vivi would have been a celestial dragon

Comment: `filthy common folk` huh. Celestial Dragons are really worst :). Thanks for information

Answer (score 5):

Nope. Although her family belonged to the one of the 20 Kings who participated in Alliance during [Void Century](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Twenty_Kings#Void_Century) , They did not move to Mariejois.

> The World Nobles, also known as the Celestial Dragons, are direct descendants of the founding kings **who moved to Mariejois.** As such, these Nobles possess the authority to do as they please, simply due to their heritage.

Comment: so you mean then moves to Mariejois and that is the reason they are Celestial Dragon.

Comment: Correct. Celestial dragons is the name given to the descendants of 19 out of 20 Kings that help establish the World Government.

Answer (score 0):

Nefertari family rejected to be Tenryubito back in the day WG was created.

When someone rejects the title all the descent loses the blood right.

Comment: Any citation to go along with that statement?

Comment: For the 1st:  ch.722   ep.653      For the 2nd: ch.760+  ep.699+   (I think)  Doffy tried to return to be a Ternryubito despite his father´s previous acts, but couldn´t

Comment: If you could [edit](http://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/26118/edit) this information into your answer (and maybe even add a picture of it if possible) it would be a better answer.